# Rearranging a formula with e in it

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$V_C = V_S\left(1-e^{\left(\frac{-t}{RC}\right)}\right)$$

This is the formula I have to rearrange to find 't'.
This is what I have so far:

$$t = -\ln\left(\frac{V_C}{V_S} + 1\right)RC$$

When I input my numbers into a calculator it comes up whis a math error, if anyone can see what I've done wrong please could you help?
Thanks!

Comment: Check the signs of what are inside of the logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
$$t= -\ln\left(1-\frac{V_C}{V_S}\right)RC.$$
The first step is:
$$\frac{V_C}{V_S}=1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$$
so subtracting $\frac{V_C}{V_S}$ and adding $e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$ to each side gives
$$e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}= 1-\frac{V_C}{V_S}.$$
I think you can continue from here.